# Regular expression performance issue

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I've got a long string which contains about 100 parameters (string parameterName) matching the following pattern:

```
parameterName + "(Whitespace | CarriageReturn | Tabulation | Period | Underline | Digit | Letter | QuotationMark | Slash)* DATA Whitespace Hexadecimal"
```

I've tried to used this regular expression, but it works a way too long:

```
parameterName + "[\\s\\S]*DATA\\s0x[0-9A-F]{4,8}"
```

This messy one works a little better:

```
parameterName + "(\\s|\r|\n|\t|\\.|[_0-9A-z]|\"|/)*DATA\\s0x[0-9A-F]{4,8}"
```

I'd use **".*"**, however, it doesn't match **"\n"**.

I've tried **"(.|\n)"**, but it works even slower than **"[\s\S]"**.

Is there any way to improve this regular expression?

Comment: You can compile your regex FOR SPEED.

Comment: [C# Regex Performance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance)

Comment: FYI, in order to make the wildcard `.` match newlines you can just use the `s` flag.

Comment: I'd precompile my regex, though I've got the cycle foreach(string parameterName in parameterNameArray) which contains regex compilation for each parameterName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
(?>(?>[^D]+|D(?!ATA))*)DATA\\s0x[0-9A-F]{4,8}

(?>                # atomic grouping (no backtracking)
    (?>            # atomic grouping (no backtracking)
        [^D]+      # anything but a D
    |              # or
        D(?!ATA)   # a D not followed by ATA
    )*             # zero or more time
)
```

**The idea**

The idea is to get to the `DATA` without asking ourselves any question, *and to not go any further and then backtrack to it*.

If you use `.*DATA` on a string like `DATA321`, see what the regex engine does:

- `.*` eats up all the string
- There's no `DATA` to be found, so step by step the engine will backtrack and try these combinations: `.*` will eat only `DATA32`, then `DATA3`, then `DATA`... then *nothing* and that's when we find our match.

Same thing happens if you use `.*?DATA` on `123DATA`: `.*?` will try to match nothing, then `1`, then `12`...

On each try we have to check there is no `DATA` after the place where `.*` stopped, and this is time consuming. With the `[^D]+|D(?!ATA)` we ensure we stop exactly when we need to - not before, not after.

**Beware of backtracking**

So why not use `(?:[^D]|D(?!ATA))` instead of these weird atomic grouping?

This is all good and working fine when we have a match to be found. But what happens when we don't? Before declaring failure, the regex have to try ALL possible combinations. And when you have something like `(.*)*` at each character the regex engine can use both the inside `*` or the outside one.

Which means the number of combinations very rapidely becomes **huge**. We want to *not* try all of these: we know that we stopped at the right place, if we didn't find a match right away we never will. Hence the atomic grouping (apparently .NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers).

You can see what I mean [over here](http://regex101.com/r/bN4oB0/#debugger): 80'000 steps to check a 15 character long string that will never match.

This is discussed more in depth (and better put than what I could ever do) in this great article by Friedl, regex guru, [over here](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol1_2/tpj0102-0006.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I've got "nested quantifier exception", trying to use it.

Comment: Nested quantifiers can indeed lead to "catastrophic backtracking", so you have to use possessive quantifier to avoid the issue. I guess the C# module doesn't recognize it and forbids it altogether...

Comment: It is solved only by removing + in ++ and *+. It seems to work faster, though I have to test it. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Ivan: please don't do that, it's actually pretty "dangerous". I'll explain why in a minute.

Comment: @Ivan: Edited answer, hope it's clearer - let me know if that helps!

Comment: @Robin, .NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers.  It interpreted the `[^D]++` in your original answer as `([^D]+)+`; that's what caused the "nested quantifier" exception.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Yeah, saw that researching the error... It does seem to support atomic grouping though. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It helped. One more thing to the same topic: will the no backtracking "?>" work inside "?<=" group? Like, (?<=parameterNameHere(?>(?>[^D]+|D(?!ATA))*)DATA\\s0x)[0-9A-F]{4,8}. I've tried this as well, but with no success.

Comment: @Ivan: Usually you can't use quantifiers inside a lookbehind, they have to be of fixed length. However, the .NET framework is supposed to be (*the* only?) one of the only ones supporting full variable length lookbehinds... I have no experience with this feature though. You're probably better of using capturing groups: in `parameterNameHere(?>(?>[^D]+|D(?!ATA))*)DATA\\s0x([0-9A-F]{4,8})` what you want will be inside the first capturing group.

Comment: @Robin thanks for the comment. Yes, the overall problem is solved, time was reduced to about 250ms from over 4000ms. The further replace task was solved by using groups and Regex.Replace(string result, string pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator). Thank you once again.